# This is a seal on a painting. I have identified several but 8 are still unknown. Please can anyone read this seal?

Tags: seal

[image] This is a seal on the lower left corner of a large scroll.

Answer (score 2):

imo, these character are in non-stardand small script; my best guess:

the bottom right is "春" (u+6625)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=春](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%98%A5)

top left is "堂" (u+5802)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=堂](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A0%82)

bottom left is "製" (u+88fd)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=製](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A3%BD)

top right character, not yet recognised :(

Comment: Maybe the top right is actually two, 音 and something else?

Comment: Maybe it’s 意. Nonstandard shape as you mentioned..